# Will an observer see the light hit the same spot as the ones in a spaceship? Why?

Tags: special-relativity

In terms of special relativity. An astronaut marks a spot `a` at the ceiling and shoots a light beam at `a` in a spaceship. The spaceship, astronaut and light source are stationary in an inertial frame `A`. For an observer outside the spaceship, stationary in an inertial frame `B`, `B` and `A` having a relative speed `v`, will she see the light beam hit the same spot `a` or to its left or right?
[image]

If the observer in `B` sees the shooting angle $\theta$ the same as the astronaut in `A`, then she will see the light hit a spot `b` to the left of `a` because of spaceship movement. If she must see the same hit spot `a`, then the shooting angle seen by `B` must be smaller.

How can its conclusion be reasoned from the two postulates of special relativity? Or does it need additional assumptions to reason? I want to know the deductive logic leading to this.

Comment: A should define the stationary frame, and B should define the moving frame. Ofc it doesn't matter for math, but it's less confusing. You introduce the rocket as a stationary fame, and then in the pic it's moving. Setting up problems clearly helps askers and answerers.

Answer (score 12):

If an event occurs in one reference frame, that event occurs in all reference frames. Different observers may disagree about the time between two events, or this distance between two events, or even (for space like-separated events) which event occurs before the other.  Different observers will *certainly* disagree about things like angles.  But everyone will agree about which events have occurred or not.

To convert your scenario from a continuum example to an event-base example, suppose that your light beam is just a pulse, and the ceiling is covered in old-fashioned film which turns dark when it's illuminated.
The observer in the ship will see the film at position `a` go dark — perhaps `a` is 40% of the way from the aft end the film to the forward end.  The external observer won't agree about the *length* of the film, due to relativistic contraction.  But the external observer *will* agree that the exposed part of the film is 40% of the way from the aft end.

Comment: I agree with "If an event occurs in one reference frame, that event occurs in all reference frames". Is it treated as a standalone postulate in the theory or derivative from other postulates? Thanks

Comment: Also to be precise, does this proposition define "event" as interaction between matters, as "shoot light beam with theta angle" can also be an event but it does not happen the same across frames?

Comment: I'm using "event" to mean "a thing which can be specified by four coordinates $(t_0,x_0,y_0,z_0)$" — that is, something that has both a place and a time. The transition from "unexposed film" to "exposed film" is something that can be pinpointed in time. In a [spacetime diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime_diagram), an event is represented by a point, as contrasted with e.g. the "worldline" of an object which exists for some nonzero duration. The Lorentz transformation is all about representing the same sets of events in different coordinate systems.

Answer (score 8):

Imagine the light beam is a powerful laser and burns a mark on the ceiling. This is an undeniable event and is an element of reality that all observers have to agree on. If one observer sees a burn mark on the ceiling, then they all have to agree on this. They do not have separate realities. The observers do disagree on other things like the angle of the path followed by the beam. [See the animation I posted in another answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/799113/a-bar-that-appears-straight-in-one-reference-frame-appears-bent-in-another/799178#799178) that demonstrates how a beam can appear to travel different angle paths in different reference frames.

Answer (score 4):

If observer A see the light hit the mark in the ceiling, then observer B also see the light hit the mark in the ceiling.

Observer B may see a shorter spaceship than A does, due to length contraction if v is close to c. In that case, the observed angle Θ will be different (closer to 90 degrees for B), the mark in the ceiling will be narrower – but it will still be hit by the (blueshifted) light beam.

For B, all horizontal distances will seem shorter. But if the spot is in the middle of the spaceship for A, then the spot is in the middle of the shorter spaceship for B too.

Answer (score 3):

The light will hit the same spot (let us say a mark painted in the wall), the light will make different angles with the horizontal in the different frames

Answer (score 2):

We can think of 2 events in space-time. A pulse being emitted by the source and the spot receiving the pulse.

Let's take the angle $\theta = 90^{\circ}$ to simplify the analysis, and the z axis being the light direction. As the fields are orthogonal to the wave direction, we can suppose the electric field in the y-direction and the magnetic fields in the x-direction.

If the relative velocity of the ship is in the x-direction, the tensor $F_{\mu\nu}$ is Lorentz transformed. Besides the $B_x$, a component $B_z$ of the magnetic field is now present in the frame outside the ship. The direction of the wave must now have an angle with the z-direction in order to stay orthogonal to the fields.

So, the angle of the wave changes for another frame. If both frames agrees that the event 'pulse hit the spot' happens at $x_1 = x'_1$ for example, then $x_0 \neq x'_0$ for the event 'pulse leaves the source'.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have said, the light hits the same spot in both frames. However, what you seem to be more interested in, is what principle in physics makes us sure of that. It is not explicit in the two postulates of SR, but instead is a reflection of a separate assumption implicit in all of physics, namely that, in the sense I am about to describe, there is only one reality. If I drop my keys by a bus stop while walking down the Strand towards Fleet Street when my watch says 12 O'clock, then I drop my keys by the same bus stop at noon London time in all reference frames. The way we label that event will vary by reference frame- but the fact that the event happened where it did in spacetime remains true in every frame. The time at which I dropped my keys- 12 O'clock London time- is given a different label by someone living in Paris, who will say I dropped them at 1pm Central European Time. The speed and direction in which I was moving will be different in the frame of a person travelling along the Strand in a taxi. But everyone will agree that I dropped my keys by the bus stop when it was 12 O'clock on my watch.

Importantly, the direction of motion can vary by reference frame. Consider my dropped keys. In my frame, the keys might drop vertically downwards. What I mean by that is that the vertical coordinate of the keys decreases while their horizontal position remains unchanged. In the frame of a person travelling along the Strand in a taxi, my keys do not drop vertically, because in that frame the horizontal position of the keys is continually changing as they accelerate downwards, so the keys move on a curved path. Where you have perhaps confused yourself is that you have not taken the frame-dependence of directions into account. The 'shooting angle' followed by the ray of light in one frame is not the same as the shooting angle in the other, for the same reason that the direction followed by my falling keys is not the same in my frame as it is in the frame of the person in the passing taxi.